# How to make a NodeJS app use Google Compute Engine Service Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've created a Google Compute Engine instance and assigned the "Default Compute Engine Service Account" to it with specific rights: access to GBQ, for instance.

I've SSHed into this instance and checked configs with `gcloud config list` command. It seems right, gcloud is logged in and using the "Default Compute Engine Service Account". Probably with the GBQ access too.

Now I want a NodeJS app to use this account.

I used to create a custom Service Account and export a JSON key from it. Then I used it like that:

```
import { BigQuery } from '@google-cloud/bigquery'

const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery({
  keyFilename: './my-key-file.json',
  projectId: 'my-project-id'
})

export default async () => {
  const response = await bigqueryClient
    .dataset('dataset_name')
    .table('table_name')
    .createLoadJob('./output.csv', { format: 'CSV' })
}
```

Is it possible to just use the account the GCE Instance is using without creating a custom service account? Something like that:

```
...
const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery()
...
```

so that it would somehow catch the compute engine account?

Comment: If you do not specify a service account, the Google Client Libraries will use ADC to find credentials. This means create the Client() without specifying a service account.  What does the API documentation show you?

Comment: Agree on the above comment. You can run 'gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=[KEY_FILE]' to create configuration files for the SDK to authenticate calls using a service account. Additionally, if you run 'gcloud auth login' configuration files will be created to authenticate the API calls with your user account: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing